# Ошибка импорта matplotlib в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, matplotlib, python-import

Я совсем новичок в python, и столкнувшись с этой проблемой я не могу продолжать обучение. Вот что происходит когда я запускаю код в Pycharm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и после того как я нажимаю на "Закрыть программу" в логе выскакивает "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)".
После этого я удалял проект, делал новый, пару раз саму библиотеку удалял и устанавливал, ничего не помогло. Потом я попытался скачать эту библиотеку без помощи Pycharm, вроде все хорошо, но как только пытаюсь запустить этот же код в Geany, Python тут же прекращает работу.
До этого работал с библиотекой pygame и все работало отлично, а сейчас не знаю.
Еще хочу добавить что ошибки еще были в тот момент, когда я первый раз скачивал эту библиотеку.
P.S. я выяснил, что проблема именно в строке "import matplotlib.pyplot"
Для лучшего понимания вопроса вот серия скриншотов:
1. Удаляю matplotlib [image: Удаляю matplotlib с помощью консоли]
2. Снова скачиваю matplotlib c помощью pip[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Запускаю код. Ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Окей, создаю новый проект[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Скачиваю matplotlib с помощью Pycharm [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Импортирую matplotlib, та же ошибка, скриншот прикреплять не буду

Comment: А если нажать "Показать подробности", что там?

Comment: @МарияРиваненкова там ничего особенного, "имя приложения : python.exe", и другая информация которая не дает четкого представления о проблеме, но к счастью я уже смог решить

Answer (score 1):

Ухты, все оказалось куда проще чем я думал. Я удалил Pycharm, удалил Python, заново установил и то и другое, и теперь все работает. В чем была ошибка непонятно, но хорошо что это решилось так просто(извиняюсь что не сделал это до того как задал вопрос)

Comment: Ничего себе просто. Для полного комплекта еще надо было ОС переустановить.

Answer (score 0):

напиши в консоли pip install metaplotlib и если у тебя не установлен питон то его можно установить на офф сайте)

Comment: Да, я вводил pip install matplotlib, у меня успешно началось и закончилось скачивание, но когда я перехожу в python и пишу "import matplotlib" Python прекращает свою работу

Comment: импортируй модуль в самом pycharm, в худшем случае подключи виртуальное окружение